# UserActivityID auto_increment

Tags: java

i have problem with inserting value from java to mysql, its still confusing me about how to insert auto increment some people say that, it will be automatically without inserting value. also, i have try with add set Int(1,null) and error there.

```
public void mase(){

   String time=dateFormat.format(date);

   String SQLTIME="INSERT INTO history (UserActivityID, UserTimeActivity, UserActivity) VALUES (null,?,?)";

try {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "?");

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement prstm=con.prepareStatement(SQLTIME);
    prstm = con.prepareStatement(SQLTIME,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    prstm.setString(1, time);
    prstm.setString(2,"Cash Withdraw");
    int rowsInserted = prstm.executeUpdate();
    if (rowsInserted > 0) {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," inserted successfully!");
     }

} catch (SQLException | HeadlessException | ClassCastException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex); 
}
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, time);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the `UserActivityID` from your command, the DB manager will insert it for you.

`String SQLTIME="INSERT INTO history (UserTimeActivity, UserActivity) VALUES (?,?)"`;